# BoofCV:I 'm trying to Run ExampleTrackingKlt.java and it can not find once of library

Tags: java, boofcv

### I 'm trying to Run [ExampleTrackingKlt](http://boofcv.org/index.php?title=Example_Webcam_Capture) which is BoofCV examble and it can not find

> boofcv.io.image.ConvertBufferedImage;

I'm try to use boofcv.core.image.ConvertBufferedImage;
but it doesn't work.

So How could I find boofcv.io.image.ConvertBufferedImage;
I can not find it on library folder because I've added all of JAR of boofcv to my project.

[Link of BoofCV](http://boofcv.org/)

This image show the list of library I use for the project which all of the boofcv JAR folder

[image: This image show the list of library I use for the project]

I  try use

> boofcv.core.image.ConvertBufferedImage

but it still doesn't work.
Here is the Error message

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory  
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam.<clinit>(Webcam.java:38) at   com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam.<clinit>(Webcam.java:38)  
    at boofcv.io.webcamcapture.UtilWebcamCapture.openDefault(UtilWebcamCapture.java:36)  
    at exampletrackingklt.ExampleTrackingKlt.main(ExampleTrackingKlt.java:31)  
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory  
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)  
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)  
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)  
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)  
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)  
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)  
    ... 3 more    
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam.<clinit>(Webcam.java:38)   
Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using v 0.18 or lesser you should use `boofcv.core.image.ConvertBufferedImage` 
and add "BoofCV-ip-0.18.jar" to your project build path if you are programming normal Java project 
or if you are using Maven add the dependency to your maven dependencies

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.boofcv</groupId>
  <artifactId>ip</artifactId>
  <version>0.18</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: How to add Maven dependency on Netbeans,sir? 
@Jileni Bouguima

Comment: File > New Project; Select in Categories "Maven" and in Projects "Java Application"  > Next > Finish, open "Project Files/pom.xml" ,   in dependencies add your bootcv dependencies, that's all